# How can you edit currency in datagrip?

Tags: postgresql, ide, currency, datagrip

I have a problem that datagrip on rows with "money" type adds local currency, I guess... But instead of currency it jsut shows "?" like this:
[Wrong Currency Showcase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lXtl.png)

I prefer just turn off this function because it's breaking my pg_dump "COPY" because it can't parse this "*some_num* ?" to money format. But if that's not possible, at least I want it to show my locale currency

Comment: [Don't use money](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_money)

Comment: Thanks for an advise. But that's totally not an answer to my question.

Comment: No way to disable it, unfortunately. 
The questions seem to be caused by a wrong encoding.

Comment: And... Money is not the best type, for sure. It is better to use 2 int values